# Is there a specialized algorithm to collapse (to aggregate) the missing numbers in the set?

Tags: algorithm, aggregate

That is an array of integer numbers `[3, 4, 5, 10, 10000`] to transform into an array / an list like `['1, 2', 3, 4, 5, '6-9', 10, '11-9999', 10000]`. This is a small example, but it is clear that the loop through all numbers from 1 to 10000 are not effective.

Comment: If you order the set, should be enough to check if x[i+1] - x[i] = 1 , and if that's not true, add the interval ('x[i],x[i+1]') to the missing item list...

Comment: Are elements just integers? Or they can be float?

Comment: @Fallen: Suppose that the initial array is sorted.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo: To get started and to keep things simple gave example for integers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the array is sorted, it all boils down to:

```
for i = 0 ... array.Length-1
  write array[i]
  switch( array[i+1] - array[i])
    case 1:
      do nothing;
    case 2:
      write "'" + (array[i]+1) + "'";
    case 3:
      write "'" + (array[i]+1) + " , " + (array[i]+2) + "'"
    default:
      write "'" + (array[i]+1) + " - " + (array[i+1]-1) + "'"
write array[array.Length]
```

Note: the various switch are to stick to your "presentation" of the new array with the missing items; if that's not necessary, just pout an if(array[i+1]-array[i] > 1)

Answer (score 1):

Let the initial array is arr[] and length of arr is N. So the algorithm goes as following:

```
for(i=0;i<N-1;i++){
    if(ar[i+1]-ar[i]!=1){
        add segment ar[i]+1 to ar[i+1]-1 to new array
    }
    add arr[i] to new array
}
```

Note that you should add `10000+1` as the last value of arr[].